# Nuget Pack .nuspec file Azure Pipeline Doesn't pick up csproj Assembly properties. But same project can pack locally

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, nuspec

Following is what i see in Pipeline Nuget Pack task

What i am trying to do is Nuget Pack using `**/*.nuspec` files.

This project could be packed using nuget pack locally without issue

For some reason its not picking property values in csproj assembly file

### What's IN ASSEMBLY file

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("SOMECOMPANY.Mapping")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("SOMECOMPANY Mapping")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("SOMECOMPANY")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("SOMECOMPANY.Mapping")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2018")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("SOMECOMPANY")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("9c3a7a3b-964b-4d85-b543-8bcc55fc6589")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

### WHATS in PIPE LINE

```
##[section]Starting: NuGet pack
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Azure Artifacts and MyGet. Uses NuGet.exe and works with .NET Framework apps. For .NET Core and .NET Standard apps, use the .NET Core task.
Version      : 2.156.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget
==============================================================================

[command]C:\windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
##[warning]The automatic package versioning and include referenced projects options do not work together. Referenced projects will not inherit the custom version provided by the automatic versioning settings.
Attempting to pack file: d:\a\1\s\src\SOMECOMPANY.Core\SOMECOMPANY.Mapping\SOMECOMPANY.Mapping.nuspec
[command]C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\NuGet\4.1.0\x64\nuget.exe pack d:\a\1\s\src\SOMECOMPANY.Core\SOMECOMPANY.Mapping\SOMECOMPANY.Mapping.nuspec -NonInteractive -OutputDirectory d:\a\1\a -IncludeReferencedProjects -Symbols -version 1.0.0-CI-20190824-170629 -Verbosity Detailed
System.Exception: Id is required.
NuGet Version: 4.1.0.2450
**Authors is required.
Attempting to build package from 'SOMECOMPANY.Mapping.nuspec'.
Description is required.**
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.Validate(Manifest manifest)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.ReadManifest(Stream stream, String basePath, Func`2 propertyProvider)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder..ctor(String path, String basePath, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean includeEmptyDirectories)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.CreatePackageBuilderFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)

**##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(System.Exception:** **Id is required.
Authors is required.
Description is required.**
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.Validate(Manifest manifest)
   at NuGet.Packaging.Manifest.ReadFrom(Stream stream, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean validateSchema)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder.ReadManifest(Stream stream, String basePath, Func`2 propertyProvider)
   at NuGet.Packaging.PackageBuilder..ctor(String path, String basePath, Func`2 propertyProvider, Boolean includeEmptyDirectories)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.CreatePackageBuilderFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromNuspec(String path)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args))
##[error]An error occurred while trying to pack the files.
##[section]Finishing: NuGet pack
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. assembly values doesn't get picked up when you pack using nuspec. it only gets picked up when using pack on csproj file.

what I did was specifying all csproj files in pack

MSdn https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec